# join two tables on 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following two tables as seen in the picture:

```
Table1
ID / Modif / Value
a / mb / Ki
a / x / Jim

Table 2
ID / Modif / Value
a / y / K
a / x / Kat
a / z / Ma





Desired Result:
ID / Modif / Value
a / mb / Ki
```

need to see all the records from table1 that have the same ID in table2 but different Modif value.

Can you help?

Comment: You tried different Join types, like (LEFT join, RIGHT join) etc?

Comment: So just to clarify... You want all rows from table 1 that have at least 1 entry in table 2 with the same ID, but NO entries in table 2 with both the same ID and same Modif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I got busy with my own work, Sounds to me like all you need is the NOT IN command, ie:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID, c.Modif, c.Value
FROM Table1 c
JOIN Table2 o on o.ID = c.ID 
WHERE c.Modif NOT IN
(
  Select o.Modif FROM Table2 o
)
```

That's how I would have approached your situation, not sure if it the best way or not.

See [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/225ff6/17/0) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only rows from first table, use `exists`:

```
select  distinct c.* --, o.ID AS oID, o.Modif AS OModif, o.Val As OVal
from Table1 c
where not exists (select * from Table2  o where c.id = o.id and c.Modif = o.Modif)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the join like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.* --, o.ID AS oID, o.Modif AS OModif, o.Val As OVal 
FROM
  Table1 c
  JOIN Table2 o ON c.ID = o.ID
        -- ensures there is at least 1 entry with same ID. 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 o2 ON c.ID = o2.ID AND c.Modif = o.Modif 
WHERE o2.Modif IS NULL
       -- left join + NULL check ensures there are NO entries with same ID and same Modif
```

If I understand your question right this should get the desired result